# how i can lazy load thumbnail images to scroll view vertically with pages?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

i have photo gallery which loaded to scroll view vertically and i only want to load visible pages to avoid memory issues like table views did. Is there a way to do this? i am using core data to get images and there are more than 150+ images in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this: http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/ and I'd think it would help in your scenario as well

Answer (score 0):

if you are using vertical only scroll you may use UITableView with custom UITableViewCell.

This way, you get the lazy load done.